# android, how can i close secondary sliding menu programatically

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu

i'm using sliding menu from https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu
and i know how to open and close left menu by toggle
and to show right menu

```
getSlidingMenu().showSecondaryMenu()
```

but how to close it programatically

Comment: How did this work out? I voted the question up, I find it unclear from the documentation how to to this.

Answer (score 3):

You can close both of the menus with showContent(). hope this helps.

```
if (getSlidingMenu().isSecondaryMenuShowing())
{
     getSlidingMenu().showContent();
}
```

Comment: or you can use `getSlidingMenu().toggle();`

Comment: how to use when the menu is opened ??

Answer (score 0):

The method called toggle() in SlidingMenu will close the menu that is currently showing regardless if it is the right or left menu.

I have implemented my "back button" logic like this ;

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mSlidingMenu.isSecondaryMenuShowing() || mSlidingMenu.isMenuShowing()) {
            mSlidingMenu.toggle();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

This closes any visible menu.

Comment: how to use when the menu is opened